# Excel Name Manager referring 2 ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

In MS-Excel 2016's name manager if i'm trying to add data for 2 or more consecutive cells, it's working fine. e.g.

```
='Data Sets'!$C$2:$C$5
```

Now if i want to get only 2 data i.e.

```
$C$2 & $C$5
```

I'm unable to do so. Kindly help.

[image]

Note: I'm using these for dynamic lists (INDIRECT).

Expected Output: `{"LOF";"MSAIS"}`

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've already tried to save us spending time suggesting things that don't work for you. It also helps us to better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have `test` named range, refering to **B4** and **D4** like this:

[image]

To get **B4** you need this formula:

```
=INDEX(test;1;1)
```

To get **D4** you need this formula:

```
=INDEX(test;1;1;2)
```

---

This is how the name manager looks like for two different cells:

[image]

---

In the name range more than one range is shown like this `{...}`. This is done for internal reasons by Excel. However, if it was not, the expected output should have been like this: `[{"LOF"};{"MSAIS"}]` or something similar.

Comment: @Vivyata: thanks. But this is specific to Name Manager. Let me add screen shots.

Comment: Did you find these values "ads and das" shown in name manager. e.g. we can see "LOF,MSBIP,MSAIS" in added image. because i tried the same but no values are getting populated.

Comment: @TheMightyNight - `ads` and `das` were written by me in Excel. In the name manager you give the address(es) of the range(es).

Comment: The values are not populated indeed, but they are there. You can check it by using the `index()` formulas in my answer.

Comment: @TheMightyNight - it does not show, because they are two ranges. But you can see that they exist, if you use the `=Index()` formula from my answer. Just refer the way I do.